# add_role user capability not working

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I added a role this way:

```
add_role( 
        'paar',
        __( 'Tanzpaar' ),
        array(
            'add_users' => false,
            'create_users' => false,
            'delete_users' => false,
            'remove_users' => false,
            'delete_pages' => false,
            'delete_posts' => false,
            'delete_private_pages' => false,
            'delete_private_posts' => false,
            'delete_published_pages' => false,
            'delete_published_posts' => false,
            'delete_others_pages' => false,
            'delete_others_posts' => false,
            'edit_dashboard' => false,
            'edit_files' => false,
            'edit_pages' => false,
            'edit_posts' => false,
            'edit_private_pages' => false,
            'edit_private_posts' => false,
            'edit_published_pages' => false,
            'edit_published_posts' => false,
            'edit_others_pages' => false,
            'edit_others_posts' => false,
            'edit_theme_options' => false,
            'list_users' => true,
            'manage_categories' => false,
            'manage_links' => false,
            'manage_options' => false,
            'moderate_comments' => false,
            'publish_pages' => false,
            'publish_posts' => false,
            'read_private_pages' => false,
            'read_private_posts' => false,
            'read' => true,
            'switch_themes' => false,
            'unfiltered_upload' => false,
            'upload_files' => false
        ) 
    );
```

Most of it worked. But I still can delete users. How is that possible?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: The rest of the code inside of functions.php is not relevant. I removed everything, except for the above. It did not change anything. What else do you want to see?

Comment: @BradDalton I don't understand, why you need rest of the code! This is an independent function should work its own.